# promesas en JavaScript , quiero guardar en una variable y no sé como

Tags: javascript, promesas, asincronismo

Estoy empezando a utilizar promesas y por más que leo y veo videos no logro entender como manipular los datos de esta, ya que todos los ejemplos que dan es mostrándolas por `console.log()` y no se como coger esa promesa y poder asignarla a una variable y manipularla desde esa.

estoy utilizando JavaScript puro.

```
function latitud(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        resolve(position)
      
      })
    })
  }

async function tiempo(promesa){
  let a = await promesa
 return a
}

console.log(tiempo(latitud()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asignar la promesa que devuelve latitud() a una variable y usar el método .then() para manipular los datos cuando se resuelva correctamente:

```
function latitud(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        resolve(position)
      })
  })
}

async function tiempo(promesa){
  let a = await promesa
  return a
}

let miPromesa = latitud()
miPromesa.then(position => {
  let lat = position.coords.latitude
  let long = position.coords.longitude
  console.log(`Latitud: ${lat}, Longitud: ${long}`)
  // ...
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: entiendo pero esas variables lat y long no pueden ser accesibles en mi codigo si escribo mas codigo

Comment: si están definidas con let solo son accesibles en el método then(), las puedes definir de manera global quitando el let...

Comment: ... o moviendo _lat_ y _long_ fuera del `.then()`.

Comment: @padaleiana no, las variables `lat` y `long` son variables de un entorno asíncrono. Sólo estarán disponibles, si la Promesa es resuelta, dentro del método `then`. Si se desea usar las variables de forma "global", se necesita que todo el código se ejecute en un entorno asíncrono. Hay un truco que es envolver todo en una función asíncrona autollamada, pero es un truco que no saca las variables al entorno global, lo que hace es envolver todo tu código dentro de un entorno asíncrono y da la ilusión de trabajar de forma síncrona con `await`. Saludos